# Variable in a function

Tags: scheme, closures, scope, racket

I have see the following code... The first call of `(next-num)` returns `1`, and the second returns `2`.

```
(define next-num
  (let ((num 0))
    (lambda () (set! num (+ num 1)) num)))

(next-num)   ; 1
(next-num)   ; 2
```

What I can not understand is... `num` is created by `let` inside `next-num`, it is kind of a local variable... How does scheme know that each time `next-num` is called, the value of `num` is not erased by `let ((num 0))`; How does scheme know that it is always the same `num` that we modify whenever `next-num` is called?

It seems that `num` is both local and static... How can we define a local variable, but not static?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is "lexical closure" and you're right that `num`, the "closed-over variable" is similar to a static variable, in C for example: it's only visible to code within the `let` form (its "lexical scope"), but it persists across the whole program run, rather than being re-initialized with each call to the function.

I think the part you're confused on is this: "`num` is created by let inside `next-num`, it is kind of a local variable". This isn't true because the `let` block isn't part of the `next-num` function: it's actually an expression which creates and returns the function which is then bound to `next-num`. (This is very different, e.g., from C, where functions can only be created at compile-time and by defining them at top-level. In Scheme, functions are values like integers or lists, which any expression can return).

Here's another way to write (almost) the same thing which makes it clearer that the `define` is just associating `next-num` to the value of a function-returning expression:

```
(define next-num #f) ; dummy value
(let ((num 0))
  (set! next-num
        (lambda () (set! num (+ num 1)) num)))
```

It's important to note the difference between

```
(define (some-var args ...) expression expression ...)
```

which makes `some-var` a function which executes all the `expressions` when called, and

```
(define some-var expression)
```

which binds `some-var` to the value of `expression`, evaluated then and there. Strictly speaking, the former version is unnecessary, because it's equivalent to

```
(define some-var
  (lambda (args ...) expression expression ...))
```

Your code is almost the same as this, with the addition of the lexically scoped variable, `num`, around the `lambda` form.

Finally, here's a key difference between closed-over variables and static variables, which makes closures much more powerful. If you had written the following instead:

```
(define make-next-num
  (lambda (num)
    (lambda () (set! num (+ num 1)) num)))
```

then each call to `make-next-num` would create an anonymous function with a new, distinct `num` variable, which is private to that function:

```
(define f (make-next-num 7))
(define g (make-next-num 2))

(f)  ; => 8
(g)  ; => 3
(f)  ; => 9
```

This is a really cool and powerful trick which accounts for a lot of the power of languages with lexical closures.

Edited to add: You ask how Scheme "knows" which `num` to modify when `next-num` is called. In outline, if not in implementation, this is actually pretty simple. Every expression in Scheme is evaluated in  the context of an environment (a lookup table) of variable bindings,  which are associations of names to places which can hold values. Each evaluation of a `let` form or a function call creates a new environment by extending the current environment with new bindings. To arrange to have `lambda` forms behave as closures, the implementation represents them as a structure consisting of the function itself plus the environment in which it was defined. Calls to that function are then evaluated by extending the binding environment in which the function was defined -- *not* the environment in which it was called.

Older Lisps (including Emacs Lisp until recently) had `lambda`, but not lexical scope, so although you could create anonymous functions, calls to them would be evaluated in the calling environment rather than the definition environment, and so there were no closures. I believe Scheme was the first language to get this right. Sussman and Steele's original [Lambda Papers](http://library.readscheme.org/page1.html) on the implementation of Scheme make great mind-expanding reading for anyone who wants to understand scoping, among many other things.